# How do I migrate existing code inside a .net socket server into Asp.net REST web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sockets, photon

I am trying to migrate logic from a real-time .NET based socket server into a RESTful based ASP.net web api.  The reason is because our game design changed and we no longer need to do any real-time stuff with socket servers.

In order to migrate, I need to do the following e things, but I have no experience with Asp.net so wish someone could point me in the right direction:

1) In the socket server, when a player makes a connection, we load all of that player's data from the database into an instance of the Player class, such as the player's inventory.  We keep this instance alive on the connection object on the server side so that as long as the tcp socket connection is alive, this Player object acts sort of as a cache in memory holding the player's data.  But I can't figure out what the equivalent place to put this Player instance in Asp.net Web API, would this be on the session state?

2) The game has static data that's available to all connected clients such as how much damage a weapon does. We load this data from the database into a StaticData object on the server's application instance. What's the place to hold application-wide data in Asp.net web api?

3) We do not use a MVC architecture and currently the way we communicate between client and server is we make a request (say selling an item), the server validates and process the request, and sends the updated state back to the client by serializing the updated data into an object[] array.  It seems with asp.net MVC a lot of things are "automatic" and what would be the equivalent of doing the "send request to server -> server process and sends back updated state -> client deserializes the state" in the asp.net web api world?

Comment: you may actually be looking for SignalR if you are trying to update an old sockets based app, not WebAPI.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the reason why we want to use web api is because, we don't need the functionalities of real-time communications anymore, so we are thinking RESTful is the best way?

Comment: the thing to keep in mind, when dealing with REST, is that it is purposefully stateless.  This isn't just within the Microsoft implementation, it's a core property of a proper REST API.  In a properly developed REST API `PUT` and `POST` will be idempotent, and `GET` will be nullipotent, making no changes at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, you could store that in [`Session`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

2) Similiar to `Session`, ASP has [`Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate(v=vs.140).aspx).

3) Sorry, but the question is a little too broad to be answered. The MVC pattern is not magic and you will still have to write code. You send a request to the server. It get's processed by the controller which can manipulate a model which in turn updates a view, i.e. the output of the whole process. Try this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) to get started and get a better idea of the MVC pattern in ASP.net.

Last but not least you should be aware that you might be setting yourself up for some problems further down the road if you store data in the `Application`. As your order of magnitude of users gets bigger you may want to run your application with more than one IIS worker process. Each of those worker processes has it's own Application object. Depending on how much memory the static data takes up you might run into memory problems. You should think about using memcached, redis, etc. as shared cache instead. The same goes for the Session data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!  with regard to memory problems with the Application object, do we still need to worry about this if the static data stored in the Application never changes?  In our game the static data always stay constant and is populated when the server starts and reads from the database.  We never manipulate this static data in anyway and it never changes.

Comment: You're welcome (Please accept the answer if you find it helpful :) ). The issue here is not whether or not you are updating the data, but how much memory it consumes. For one the data will have to be reloaded into memory every time your application pool recycles (configuration setting in the IIS app pool) and this can impact performance. And secondly it will drive up memory consumption. Without knowing more about your application I would say a couple of MiB shouldn't be a problem. If we are talking GiB consider a different approach to caching.

Comment: I have accepted the answer.  It is not a lot of data, no more than 10mb.  .  I didn't know the server recycles that memory.  If I put that in the start script does that mean periodically, it would read from the database and populate that object?

Comment: In that case you should be fine regarding consumption. If you haven't done so already, add a file `Global.asax` to your project. In the code behind file `Global.asax.cs` you can now define these read and populate steps inside the `Application_Start` method. Every time your application starts (or restarts) these steps will be executed.